# Respect height of absolute elements inside a relative element

Tags: html, css, css-position

Can it be possible for the height of the relatively positioned element to adjust to the height of it's child element?

---

#### [See Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/XTVbu/)

---

### HTML:

```
Items:
<div id="love">
    <textarea id="magic"></textarea>       
</div>
Dung:​​
```

### CSS:

```
#love{
    position:relative;
    background:#eee;
    width:60px;
}
#magic{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
}
```

### Output:

[image: Dungbombs!]

Comment: If you know the height of the child beforehand: Yes, just set the `padding` or `height` properties. If you allow JavaScript: Yes, do some calculations. Otherwise: No.

Comment: i did not understand the question but see this link
http://jsfiddle.net/XTVbu/5/

Comment: @SRN, blimey amazing, Can you post that as an answer and also explain what you added? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you specify absolute positioning you have to give co-ordinates to it

```
#magic{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;   
}
```

you specify x pos and y pos as 0 and 0 
outer tag adjusts according to inner tag
//unless you specify width or height to outer tag

```
#magic{
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; // x pos
    top:0; // y pos
    width:20px;
}
```

Comment: specifying xpos & ypos along with position:absoltue as above, shows as invalid property value in chrome.